# How to display java swing component in front of Stage in javafx 2.1?

Tags: javafx-2, javafx

I am using swing component like JFileChooser, Joption in javafx application. But when i click on JFilechooser then this is being behinds of Application. How to solve this problem. Please give me some suggestion. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a subclass of JFileChooser and override the createDialog method and then return a dialog with always on top setting.

```
class AlwaysOnTopFileChooser extends JFileChooser {
    protected JDialog createDialog(Component parent) throws HeadlessException {
        JDialog dialog = super.createDialog(parent);
        dialog.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
        return dialog;
    }
}
```

You will need to fill in the required constructors etc.